# Is ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options thread safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, actionmailer

I have this code in ApplicationController (Ruby on Rails 4.1):

```
before_action :make_action_mailer_use_request_host_and_protocol

def make_action_mailer_use_request_host_and_protocol
  ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:protocol] = request.protocol
  ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = request.host_with_port
  ActionMailer::Base.asset_host = "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}"
end
```

Is it thread-safe? Consider scenario:

1. Server starts processing request for host foo.example.com. It sets the host for ActionMailer.
2. Another request comes in before server finishes processing the first one, this time for host bar.example.com. Server sets ActionMailer host to bar.example.com.
3. Execution returns to the first request. Now server sends email. What will be the host in the email, foo.example.com or bar.example.com?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the method described above is not thread-safe and the scenario you have outlined would be problematic.

Creating a default_url_options method in your controller is currently [the most idiomatic (and thread-safe) way to accomplish this](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#default-url-options).

I have found Simone Carletti's [actionmailer_with_request gem](https://github.com/weppos/actionmailer_with_request) to be an ideal solution to the problem you seem to be facing.

Comment: I seem to remember a Rails ticket for this, but I can't seem to track it down in the brief time I have.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10161975)

Comment: @Aleph7 The link is not the answer, it is a way to accomplish the goal. "Unfortunately, this is not thread-safe" is the answer. This is not a link-only answer. Please pay more attention while reviewing.

Comment: This is a low quality answer. Maybe you can explain why it's not thread-safe and what makes the other solution thread-safe.